# How can I fire an app-wide event in Angular2 or observe a global variable

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following architecture:

Navbar is a component with:

```
loggedIn = false;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    this.loggedIn = authService.isAuthenticated();
  }
```

displaying different links depending on the variable

the methods in authService :

```
  isAuthenticated() : boolean {
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }

  authenticate(email: string, password: string) : Promise<void> {
    const headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });
    return this.http.post(`${apiUrl}/auth/login`, body, { headers })
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        const data = response.json();
        this.user = data.user;
        localStorage.setItem('id_token',data.token);
      });
  }
```

I want to get notified in navbar when isAuthenticated() returns another value.

Should I use an observable value in AuthService instead of just checking for the valid token? Should I emit an event in authenticate method's success?
I could only find info about parent-children event emmiters with `@input`.

Note: I am using angular2-jwt and the isAuthenticated() method is called from the auth.guard for protected routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely use an Observable subject in your AuthService. Take a look at this [link from angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service)